# GraphQL TypeDef & Resolver for array of ObjectIds (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, prisma

I have a number of documents in my `sites` collection.

These documents contain a `pages` property, which is an `Array` of `ObjectId`'s.

```
// documents in my 'sites' collection.

{
  _id: ObjectId("5e607b2643e2640056466402")
  title: "Some Title"
  ...
  pages: [ 
    ObjectId("5e57bcbd0166a10055c43bb7")
    ObjectId("5e5ba2630166a10055c5c952")
    ...
  ]
}
```

I am using GraphQL to fetch these results using Apollo & Prisma and I want to return the actual `pages` as opposed to their individual IDs.

My `schema.prisma` looks like this

```
model pages {
  id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title     String?
  uri       String?
}

model sites {
  id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  pages     String[]  @db.ObjectId
  title     String?
  url       String?
}
```

My `typeDefs.js` file looks like this:

```
  type pages {
    id: ID!                    
    title:     String           
    uri:       String
  }

  type sites {
    id:        ID!    
    pages:     [String]
    title:     String
    url:       String
  }
```

And my `resolver` looks like this:

```js
allSites: () => prisma.sites.findMany(),
```

When I send the following GraphQL request:

```
query myQuery {
  allSitesRecursive {
    title
    pages
  }
}
```

I get this response:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "allSites": [
      {
        "title": "Some Title",
        "pages": [
          "5dc9630226b1b2005952c4b5",
          "5e5797020166a10055c41f94",
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

This is fine, but I want to extract the individual `title` and `uri` from each page in the `pages` array, as opposed to just having the reference ID.

Is this possible to achieve without reorganising my data?

If so, how?

EDIT:

I have changed my `resolver` to:

```js
allSites: () => prisma.sites.findMany({ include: { pages: true } }),
```

But then I receive an error stating:

```
Invalid scalar field `pages` for include statement on model sites.
This model has no relations, so you can't use include with it.
Note, that include statements only accept relation fields.,
```

So then I change my `schema.prisma` to:

```
model pages {
  id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title     String?
  uri       String?
  sites     sites?    @relation(fields: [sitesId], references: [id]) // gets added automatically on save
  sitesId   String?   @db.ObjectId // gets added automatically on save
}

model sites {
  id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  pages     pages[]
  title     String?
  url       String?
}
```

and my `sites` `typeDefs` to:

```
  type sites {
    id:        ID!     
    pages:     [pages]
    title:     String
    url:       String
  }
```

But my response to the following GraphQL query:

```
query AllSites {
  allSites {
    pages {
      title
      uri
    }
    title
  }
}
```

is:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "allSites": [
      {
        "pages": [],
        "title": "www.some-website.com"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The `pages` array is empty, which suggests that it is not able to fetch the `pages` by reference.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you could share a minimal reproduction repo, I could take a look into what's happening here. There are a lot of moving parts.

I will say, I think the last Prisma schema you posted is the correct one for what you're trying to accomplish, something must be going awry with the resolver/query parts.

Comment: Please show the resolver for `sites/pages`. Also for clarity I recommend you use the singular form for your type names, i.e. `site` and `page` and then `site/pages` can be `[page]` instead of `[pages]`